# How to delete last element from List if it's bigger than other ones?

Tags: java, list, nodes

I need some help with Java here.
I have some classes:

Class Node:

```
class Node{
    private int elem;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int elem, Node next){
        this.elem = elem;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getElem(){
        return elem;
    }

    public void setElem(int elem){
        this.elem = elem;
    }

    public Node getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next){
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Class List:

```
class List{
    private Node first;

    public List(){
        this.first = null;
    }

    public void insert(int elem){
        this.first = new Node(elem, first);
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s = "";
        for (Node p = first; p != null; p = p.getNext()) {
            if (p != first) s += ", ";
        s += p.getElem();
        }
    return s;
    }

    public void pushSum(){
        int sum = 0;
        Node p = first;
        while(p != null){
            sum += p.getElem();
            p = p.getNext();
        }
        this.insert(sum);
    }
}
```

Let's talk a bit about `pushSum()` method just for example:
This method is supposed to insert sum of all elements at beginning of the list.
Example Input:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Example Output after pushSum()

```
15 1 2 3 4 5
```

Now I need to know how to implement a method which removes the last element from the list if that element is bigger than all other ones.
Could you guys help me? 
Thank you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List l = new List();
    l.insert(0); // this is the first pushed element. but in tree this will be the last element
    l.insert(2);
    l.insert(3);
    l.insert(5);
    l.insert(100); // this is the last pushed element but this will be the first element in the tree

    System.out.println(l);
    l.pushSum();
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

Comment: last element means the latest element or the oldest element.?. latest means the element you that you pushed finally .

Comment: Forgot to say:
Example Input for delete_Last_if_Max():
1 2 3 4 5
Example Output for delete_Last_if_Max():
1 2 3 4

Comment: can you please include your main class. with comment your first element , last element

Comment: Just for the record: before posting such a question (nicely written by the way) ... how much time did you spend trying to find your own solution? One of the crucial point when learning programming is that ability to sit down and bang your head against walls for hours, until *you* find the solution. Seriously: avoid just dropping assignments and then go "help me" (that is in essence what you did - it really doesnt matter too much that you did part A yourself ... you completely delegated the work for part B to others here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void removeLastIfLargest() {
    if (first == null)          // No elements
        return;
    if (first.getNext() == null) { // First element is alone and hence largest.
        first = null; // remove this line if you don't want this behaviour
        return;
    }
    Node n = first;
    Node p = null; // previous
    int largest = n.getElem();
    while(n.getNext() != null) {
        if (largest < n.getElem()) 
            largest = n.getElem();
        p = n;
        n = n.getNext();
    } 
    if (n.getElem() > largest)  // last is larger than previous largest
        p.setNext(null);
}
```

Output:

```
L: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 // Before
L: 1, 2, 3, 4 // After
```

Answer (score 0):

Im little confused about your indexing of the first and last elements however this is the answer

```
public Node removeLast() {
    int val = first.getElem();

    for (Node p = first; p != null; p = p.getNext()) {
        if (p.getElem() > val) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    Node f = first;
    first = first.getNext();
    return f;
}
```

results

```
input -> 1, 100, 3, 5, 101
output -> 1, 100, 3, 5

input -> 1, 100, 3, 5, 4
output -> 1, 100, 3, 5, 4
```